# Sip UPDATE method

Tags: sip, sip-server, opensips

I am new to sip protocol.I understand the normal sip mechanism like how it works.I know about sip re-invite method which is useful to update the SDP(Session Description Protocol) parameters.But recently i found UPDATE sip method which also do the same thing.my questions are

1) Why we need UPDATE sip method?

2) Which phones(like zoiper,sjphone) are sending this UPDATE request to the servers for SDP parameter changes?

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your answer can be found in the abstract of [RFC331 - The SIP UPDATE method](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3311):

> UPDATE allows a client to update parameters of a session (such as the set of media streams and their codecs) but has no impact on the state of a dialog.  In that sense, it is like a re-INVITE, but unlike re-INVITE, it can be sent before the initial INVITE has been completed.  This makes it very useful for updating session parameters within early dialogs.

To learn which phones can utilize UPDATE you'd best read the manuals.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply.I found some of the Phones that support RFC 3311 but they are not sending any UPDATE message....Can anybody tell me in which context they will send UPDATE message..